# How do I do a SQL query based on number of quantity

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I have a table containing email addresses and account numbers (amongst other data).

I have removed the other data for simplification.

```
123456, joe@place.com
123457, phil@place.com
123456, jil@place.com
123456, jane@place.com
123458, john@place.com
```

Per the example above, most accounts have multiple email addresses.

I need to create a query to tell me:

- how many accounts have 1 email address
- how many accounts have 2 email addresses
  ...
- how many accounts have 10 email addresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner query (`q`) will count how many distinct email addresses each account has. The outer query will then count how many accounts fall into each counting bucket (1, 2, 3, ...).

```
SELECT q.email_counter, COUNT(*) AS num_accounts
    FROM (SELECT account_number, 
                 COUNT(DISTINCT email_address) AS email_counter
              FROM YourTable
              GROUP BY account_number) q
    GROUP BY q.email_counter;
```

Comment: That would do it, but it would be nice with an explanation of what it does.

Comment: that works ... thanks ... but I do not understand q as it relates to email_counter as it relates to q.email_counter

Comment: @XiVix `email_counter` represents the count of distinct email addresses at each account in the inner query, which I aliased as `q`. In the outer query, `email_counter` becomes the "bucket" for counting how many accounts fall into each grouping (e.g., 1 email address, 2 email addresses, etc.)

Comment: but then what is q.email_counter ?

Comment: `q.email_counter` is the `COUNT(DISTINCT email_address)` that is calculated in the inner query.

Comment: I see in above that the count(distinct email_address) as email_counter does not have the q in front ... what is throwing me off is the whole dot thing ... I have never seen dots in the aliases and to me q, email_counter, and q.email_counter are three different aliases.

Comment: @XiVix Think of it this way. The inner query returns a result set.  You can think of that result set as an implicit table. Then q is simply an alias for that implicit table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 select acc_no, count(*) from your_table group by acc_no
```

Comment: That only tells you how many email addresses each account has, not how many acconts there are with a certain number of email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
select accountnumbers, count(*)
from yourtablename
group by accountnumbers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to get a pivoted result set of what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN cnt = 1 THEN 1 END) AS cnt1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN cnt = 2 THEN 1 END) AS cnt2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN cnt = 3 THEN 1 END) AS cnt3,
       ....
FROM ( 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, accountId
FROM accounts
GROUP BY accountId ) t
```

`cnt1` contains the number of account ids having 1 email, `cnt2` the number of account ids with 2 emails, etc.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/86f72/1)

Answer (score 0):

There are already excellent answers, However I just wanted to add a group by with having clause answer:

```
declare @intDesiredCount int = 2 --or 3 or 4 or 10
select AccountNumber
  , Count(1) as EmailAddressCount
from ContactTable
Group by AccountNumber
having Count(1) = @intDesiredCount
```

Having filters on post aggregated values, in this example the number of email addresses.